# Frequency of each repeated set of elements in a string of numbers

Tags: python, string

You are given a string. Suppose a character 'c' occurs consecutively 'X' times in the string. Replace these consecutive occurrences of the character 'c' with (X,c) in the string.

> **Input Format** : A single line of input consisting of the string.

> **Output Format** : A single line of output consisting of the modified string.

**`Sample Input`**:

```
1222311
```

**`Sample Output`**:

```
(1, 1) (3, 2) (1, 3) (2, 1)
```

I Did the problem like this:

```
def pri(l):
    print(f"({l[0]}, {l[1]})",end=" ")
    

s = input()
lis = [1,s[0]]

for i in range(len(s)):
    fr = 1
    if i<len(s)-1:
        if s[i+1] != s[i]:
            pri(lis)
            lis = [1,s[i+1]]
        else:
            lis[0] += 1
            if s[i] == s[len(s)-1]:
                pri(lis)
                break
    else:
        lis = [1,s[i]]
        pri(lis)
```

But it can only solve 4/13 testcases in the program.What can be improved in my program?
For more information on the problem,[click here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compress-the-string/problem?isFullScreen=true)

Comment: Did you test it yourself to see which test cases it fails on? Knowing that, and comparing what the output is vs what it should be will help you fix your program.

Comment: I would start with making your variable names much clearer, and add some comments to help yourself know exactly what is happening (or what you think is happening) at each step. Try taking one of the failing test cases and running through it by hand to see where you are making errors

Answer (score 0):

The exercise states:

> In this task, we would like for you to appreciate the usefulness of
> the groupby() function of itertools .

In that case, you can use `" ".join` to print the full string, and for each item in the groups print the length of the group `len(list(g))` followed by the key `k`

For example:

```
from itertools import groupby

S = input()

result = " ".join([f"({len(list(g))}, {k})" for k, g in groupby(S)])

print(result)
```

Output

```
(1, 1) (3, 2) (1, 3) (2, 1)
```

[image]